# Delete button in JSP to delete files from server

Tags: html, jsp

I am a newbie to JSP. I have created a jsp file which runs on the tomcat server. I have specified my directory location in my program. My program displays all the files from that directory and displays results in a table and creates a delete button after filename. My program is as follow(JSP file):

```
   <%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Directories</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Current Collection</h2>
    <table width="100%" border="1">

        <%
          File folder = new File("C:/Apps/eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64/eclipse");
          File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
          for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <%
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            %>
            <td><%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="delete"></td>
            <%
              }
            %>
        </tr>
        <%
          }
        %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this on my server, my output looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFgxy.png

When user click on delete button, I want the file to be deleted from my local machine. I am very new to JSP and I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:
This is my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String deleteFileName = request.getParameter("filename");
    System.out.println("you clicked on " + deleteFileName);

  }
```

This is my jsp:

```
<tr >
            <%
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            %>
            <td><%=listOfFiles[i].getName()%></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="delete" name="filename"></td>
            <%
              }
            %>
        </tr>
```

Comment: jsp is run on the server side,  if you try to delete using JSP you will only have access to delete from the server due to security issues, to delete from client you will need some kind of java applet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a HTML `<form>` tag, and specify the `action=""` attribute as a URL which will then trigger the the Servlet (or JSP) which will receive the HTTP parameters and do the action.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.